# Xcode 6 doesn't auto generate code

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I have a strange problem with `Xcode 6`. I am not exactly sure if it was this way from the beginning or only lately, but when I add new class that inherit from `UITableViewController` and such, `Xcode` does not add the *pre-generated* methods as it usually does. On top of that, when I add a new class and choose `Swift`, the file imports `Cocoa` on default instead of `UIKit`, so I have to change it manually every time.

As it doesn't prevent me from creating `classes` etc., it is a bit annoying to deal with that every time. I would appreciate some help with that issue, searching for an answer led me nowhere so far. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you are adding from iOS library not from MAC OS X library. Cocoa comes with MAC development instead of UIKit.

Comment: o.. m.. g.. how could I have missed that?? so embarrassing:) thanks bpolat for pointing that out!

Comment: No problem. We all make mistakes everyday :)

Comment: btw, if you make that an answer, I can mark ts a the correct one:)